# windows 11 ssh key generated in system32 instead of .ssh

Tags: ssh, windows-11, openssh

My windows 11 openssh is generating SSH keys under system32 folder instead of .ssh even if .ssh folder exits under my user folder. What might be the problem and how can i change it?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\XXX/.ssh/id_rsa): test
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in test
Your public key has been saved in test.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:yYCqc179NG0FJ0GXRygbcK28t9EsOaS3z7UGSo2YE8 xxx@xxx-ntb
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|        .o+..+.  |
|     .   .oo+ .  |
|    . .  .o=..   |
|   .   o ++E   . |
|  .     S +..o .o|
| .   .   ..*+.+..|
|o . . . o +oo*   |
| + .   o oo =..  |
|  .     .  =ooo. |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

---

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\XXX/.ssh/id_rsa): test2
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in test2
Your public key has been saved in test2.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:PYcbtgsYLDLiMi4WWg9MR6FV8BdLmz0epM9t4m9TM4 xxx@xxx-ntb
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|  o.+=o..        |
| o oo.o          |
|  ..  + o        |
|  . .o o + .     |
|.oo.. + S O o    |
|.o+o . + o @ o   |
|+o.o  . . + =    |
|=o  .    . * .   |
|o.        . E    |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

In the first example it's generated in system32, in second example it's generated in my home folder.

By testing i found that it's being generated in folder in which i am. Even when it's saying it should be in the .ssh/id_rsa.

Answer (score 2):

The key is created by default in file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` if you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without giving it custom name. If you put any other name for the key without an absolute path it will create the key relatively to the current working folder.

Therefore to create the key with your custom name in the custom location you have to provide full path with the desired location.